# Sum of two lists

Tags: r, list, matrix

How can I generally take the sum of the elements of two lists that contain conformable matrices?

```
  l1<-list(matrix(1,3,3),matrix(2,3,3))
  l2<-list(matrix(3,3,3),matrix(4,3,3))
```

where the sum is defined as:

```
  l3<-list(l1[[1]]+l2[[1]],l1[[2]]+l2[[2]])
```

and 'generally' implies matrices of any size and lists of any length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typical case for the `mapply` function:

```
mapply("+", l1, l2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Or slightly more concisely using `Map`, which is just `mapply` with different defaults.

```
Map("+", l1, l2)
```